# PasswordResetForm doesn't send email

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a user system on an app. Everything works fine except one thing.

When I create a user, I generate a password to keep in database and send an email to the new created user to set his own password.
So the password is in the database and I use PasswordResetForm to send an email of password reseting.

Here is the code I use:

```
reset_password_form = PasswordResetForm(data={'email': user.email})
                if reset_password_form.is_valid():
                    reset_password_form.save(request=request,
                                             use_https=True,
                                             from_email="Webmaster@mysite.com",
                                             html_email_template_name='main/password_reset/password_reset_email.html',
                                             subject_template_name="main/password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt")
```

And here is the problem, no email is sent.

So to clarify, I already use this Form in case we click on "I forgot my password" and it works very well. So There is no problems of settings for the email server.

As well the reset_password_form.is_valid() is true I can breakpoint in the if.
The user.email exists and contain a real and correct email adress.

I have the feeling that when I call save() on my form it doesn't send the message, did I do a mistake thinking it will do?

My complete view:

```
def adduser(request, id_user=None):
    modify_user = User.objects.get(id=id_user) if id_user is not None else None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if modify_user is not None:
            userform = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=modify_user)
        else:
            userform = AddUserForm(request.POST, instance=modify_user)

        profileform = AddProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
                                     instance=modify_user.profile if modify_user is not None else None)

        if userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
            user = userform.save(commit=False)
            profileuser = profileform.save(commit=False)
            if modify_user is not None:
                user.save(update_fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'])
            else:
                reset_password_form = PasswordResetForm(data={'email': user.email})
                if reset_password_form.is_valid():
                    reset_password_form.save(request=request,
                                             use_https=True,
                                             from_email="Webmaster@mantadivegiliair.com",
                                             html_email_template_name='main/password_reset/password_reset_email.html',
                                             subject_template_name="main/password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt")
                user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password(length=6))
                user.save()
                profileuser.created_by = request.user
            profileuser.user = user
            profileuser.save()
            profileform.save_m2m()
            if modify_user is not None:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                     "{} {} has been updated".format(user.first_name, user.last_name))
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                     "{} {} has been created".format(user.first_name, user.last_name))
            return redirect('profile', user.id)
        else:
            for field in userform.errors:
                if field == "__all__":
                    userform['confirm_password'].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
                else:
                    userform[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
            for field in profileform.errors:
                profileform[field].field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
    else:
        userform = AddUserForm(instance=modify_user)
        profileform = AddProfileForm(instance=modify_user.profile if modify_user is not None else None)
    return render(request, 'main/add_user.html', locals())
```

Comment: can you show your user creation view?

Comment: I updated the original

Comment: The user isn't saved yet when you save the `PasswordResetForm`. So the save method won't do anything because it will fetch users in the database with the email submitted. Move the code regarding the password reset to **after**  you save the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user isn't saved yet when you save the `PasswordResetForm`. So the `save()` method won't do anything because it will try to fetch users in the database with the email submitted.

You just need to change the order in which you do things:

```
else:  # user is new user
    user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password(length=6))
    user.save()
    reset_password_form = ...
    reset_password_form.save(...)
    profileuser.user = user
    ...
```

Comment: Yep ... yep yep yep ... I feel stupid :D Thanks for the help